# Ionic List Reorder

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've a question about reordering lists in ionic.

In my controller I have:

```
    $scope.items = [
   { id: 1, name: "Audi S4", year: 1992 },
   { id: 2, name: "BMW M5", year: 2005 },
   { id: 3, name: "Volkswagen Passat CC", year: 2009 },
   { id: 4, name: "Nissan GTR", year: 2010 },
   { id: 5, name: "Mercedes Benz c63", year: 2008}
   ];
```

In html:

```
<ion-list show-reorder="data.showReorder">
   <ion-item class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="item in items" 
                       item="item"
                       ui-sref="car({ carId: item.id})">
      <img src="http://localhost/images.php?Id={{ item.id }}">
      <h2 align="center">{{ item.name }}</h2>
      <p align="center">{{ item.year }}</p>
      <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Everything works fine with the list and reordering , when I reorder the list and go back to home state and back into this lists display state, it shows the original list.

I can't figure out how can I save the new order of the list after I reorder it? Thanks.

Comment: well because your $state get destroyed when you leave, and hence your data gets reset. you need to save the order of the data somewhere e.g. local storage or device specific storage using a cordova plugin.

Comment: How could I pass the new list from html to angular to save it?

Comment: after reordering, your `$scope.items` contains the newly reordered items, however you need them to `persist` hence you must save them somewhere, and then reload them from storage when you come back to the view.